# Sending object refrences using bundles

Tags: android, android-activity, bundle, fragment

I've noticed that you could send fragment refrences using bundles in Android using putFragment/getFragment. 
So for the question. Is there any corresponding methon to send general objects or more specifically activities?

And yes, actually I'm a c programmer who loves pointers :)

Comment: How are you passing Fragments?  I don't see those methods declared anywhere in Bundle: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by passing Activities in bundles?

Comment: fragments can be passed using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html
I consider it very useful when having instances of fragement which needs to be recreated (rotation or other reason) where it needs to retain/restore state using saveinstace.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass objects if they implement the Parcelable interface.  Read up on that here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

edit: Unfortunately this is not the same as passing an object reference.

**edit # 2**: Ah, cool.  Did not know about that API.  Unfortunately it does not work how you think it does, take a look at it here: [FragmentManagerImpl#putFragment](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#FragmentManagerImpl.putFragment%28android.os.Bundle,java.lang.String,android.support.v4.app.Fragment%29)

All that is doing is storing the `mIndex` variable of the Fragment passed in as `putInt()` in the Bundle.

If you then look here: [Fragment.mIndex](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.java#Fragment.0mIndex)

You can see that Android just keeps an internal list of Fragments and that is how it restores the Fragment, not through its reference.  So unfortunately this doesn't store the memory reference at all.  I'm afraid what you are trying to do isn't possible and you have to implement `Parcelable` to achieve similar behavior.

Comment: Nope, not what im looking for. As Point out i need a reference, not an copy of the object.

Comment: yep fun. I'm aware it doesn't store reference, but it works like it does. Important thing is that the same instance is retrevied, that is; not a copy. Implementing Parcable/Seriaizable would produce a copy which isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: @user2679998 Sorry, but you won't find much else.  Is this just for curiosity?  You shouldn't ever have a need to put an Activity in a Bundle.  Your C mindset will have to change coming over to Android. :P